# Display svg on canvas

Tags: java, canvas, svg, batik

I want to display some images on a canvas accordingly to screen dimension without losing the image resolution.

If I use a simple png or jpeg, I will see the image pixelized on a big screen.

What I am thinking is to use svg files and display them on the janvas. Is something like that possible? (I tried to use Apache Batik without a possitive result)

if this is not possible, can you think any other alternative?

Comment: have you tried the example here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SVGCanvasDemo.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Commons has [`Batik Swing component`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html) containing special canvas [`JSVGCanvas`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/swing/JSVGCanvas.html). This is the best approach you can find.

> The goal of the `Batik Swing` component module is to provide a `Swing` component that can **used to display `SVG` documents**. With the `JSVGCanvas` class, you can easily display an SVG document (from a URI or a DOM tree) and allow the user to manipulate it, such as rotating, zooming, panning, selecting text or activating hyperlinks.

---

> I tried to use Apache Batik without a possitive result

Any problem you can share with us? [Here](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SVGCanvasDemo.htm) you will find how to implement it.

```
public SVGCanvasDemo(JFrame frame) {
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add("Center", svgCanvas);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    svgCanvas.setURI("file:/c:/files/hungryminds/rectangles.svg");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. One more question just to understand how this works. if I want to display multiple images on the canvas, I have to use multiple JSVGCanvas instances?

Comment: yes, as described in the component: *while displaying or manipulating **an SVG document.***

Comment: I have the following error "org.w3c.dom.svg does not exist" when I import batik's files in my project. "org/w3c/dom/svg" folder does not exist inside the downloaded zip files